# Is it typical for a Javascript function to return a value of undefined intentionally?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and am wondering if intentionally returning a value of undefined from a function is a common practice.

For example, should a divide() function be implemented like this:

```
var divide1 = function (x, y) {
    if (y === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return x/y;
};
```

or like this?

```
var divide2 = function (x, y) {
    if (y === 0) {
        throw new Error("Can't divide by 0");
    }

    return x/y;
};
```

I assume that returning undefined is typically reserved for functions with no return values (equivalent of void in Java or C#).

Comment: Second one is definitely the better solution, where you have properly handled the exception.

Comment: Raised an exception, not so much handled it.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh yes, `raised` indeed.

Comment: This question is quite subjective as it is framed - but it would nevertheless be interesting to find out if there's a difference between `return undefined` and `return`, according to the spec as well as browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock It's funny, but undefined is not reserved word, so one could do this `function f(){var undefined = 42; return undefined}`. So simple `return;` is more reliable to return real `undefined`.

Comment: @Alexey Ten: I forgot about that. That clears it up.

Comment: Unless the thing you are checking for is vitally important to the running of your script, raising an error isn't necessarily better as it forces all your other code calling it to catch the error. Typically, it's better to return an "error" value that you can check for, like `false`. Keep in mind you'll need to do strict checking, `retVal === false`, in case your function may also return a 0 or empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default:

```
function foo() {}
console.log(foo());
```

But it turned out it's not a good choice. Code which can run into an exceptional state shouldn't do so silently. A lot of errors in JavaScript slip through the cracks because the code doesn't break violently when something goes wrong.

So unless you're an exceptional good developer and you can guarantee that everyone who will ever touch this code is on the same level and you never make mistakes, you can return `undefined`. I, myself, would throw an exception.

Turns out I'm not a good-enough developer :-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that throwing an exception is the best choice, but I'm wondering if this is the approach typically taken in major libraries like JQuery? Just trying to get a feel for how popular each of these approaches are out in the wild.

Comment: All major libraries that I know of avoid this. jQuery is a special case since it simply returns empty lists when a selector doesn't match, so that's kind of like returning a "safe" undefined which doesn't cause any exceptions/problems (but at the same time makes it hard to spot bugs). That said, you can think of JavaScript (the language and the runtime) as the most used framework. In this case, the answer is yes, the most used framework does it and it causes a lot of problems. I'm not 100% sure but CoffeeScript doesn't support this global variable anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume that returning undefined is typically reserved for functions with no return values (equivalent of void in Java or C#).

As in Java or C#, you can also write `return;`.

These three functions are returning the same thing:

```
function VOID () {
  return;
}


function VOID () {
  return undefined;
}


function VOID () {

}
```